What is a good alternative for Scroll Element Into View that works in Firefox?
I stumbled upon a problem with scrolling the website to a desired locator when testing on Firefox using Robot Framework. Whenever I have a simple Scroll Element Into View in my test case, it results in a MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException. The same test cases work perfectly fine on Chrome or Edge.
As I've found out, it is an open issue with RF's SeleniumLibrary. Is there any elegant alternative to this? The hacky solutions like Set Window Rect with some enormous values or scrolling using JavaScript with some arbitrary value isn't really elegant nor portable. Is there anything that is as simple to use as Scroll Element Into View, yet works with Firefox, too?
